# Access to a page only if a certificate is installed

Tags: java, php, .htaccess

goodmorning guys!

i have another trouble ahead of me...
i need to limit the access of the private area of a website, you'll say.. put a login ;D 
already done; but my client keep asking me to limit more, he thought about a certificate that the user need to download in order to  use the platform... here's the problem as i know PHP doesn't permit the access to the local computer.... so i thought to use a java plugin and then  make it communicate in someway with php... is this a possible solution? are there better options?

Thanks.

Fabio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HTTPS with client certificates. Configuration of the server is needed in this case, it's not handled in PHP.

Comment: but can i create an ssl certificate for each user?

Comment: No, private-public keys is a scheme where private key is private and in this case it belongs to the user. No point in using certificates if you generate them for your clients.